# as you write in a queue and waiting for your response on another using service bus azure

Tags: python, amqp, servicebus

I'm using the sdk of the service bus to send to a queue and listen for the answer in another, but I can not find valid examples of how to make that flow. My biggest difficulty is being able to set reply_to and reply_to_group_id, as I did in the old versions directly in the MessageProperties, now in the class Message I am in doubt with what to inform in the index 'message' to achieve this objective

Answer (score 0):

The `Message` class has a property called [`properties`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/common/message.py#L57) which is an instance of [`uamqp.message.MessageProperties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/uamqp/uamqp.message.messageproperties?view=azure-python) which has the `reply_to` (and `reply_to_group_id`) property that you are looking for.

```py
from azure.servicebus import Message

message = Message(
    body="Hello World!"
)
message.properties.reply_to="replyTo"
message.properties.reply_to_group_id="replyGroupId"
```

You can read more about [AMQP Request-Response Operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-request-response) with Service Bus in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

to add to @pramodValavala's answer, here's how you do it with the v7.0 https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/7.0.0/

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusMessage

message = ServiceBusMessage("hello world")

# set using application_properties

message.application_properties = {'reply_to': 'abc'}
```